# How to make an accurate delay function in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, time

I'm making a music composer and to play the notes i'm waiting for the time (in ms) to pass before playing the next notes, i've seen that this seems farily inaccurate with sometimes up to 10ms of inaccuracy, is there a way i can make a more accurate timeout or delay function to get down to 0/1 ms of discrepancy?
My code currently is:

```
function delayMs(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms)
    })
}
```

with the "tick" function:

```
        while (this.state.isPlaying) {
            const { song, settings } = this.state
            let msPerBPM = Math.floor(60000 / settings.bpm.value)
            await delayMs(msPerBPM)
            this.handleTick()
        }
```

i'm able to use service workers as i've noticed that i get this issue with delays from re renders in react.

Comment: In short, no. You're never going to get millisecond accuracy of `setTimeout` in javascript

Comment: it always goes to queue once timout finishes so there is no guarentee that it will be executed right away. With workers it might or might not be worse depending what exactly you are doing. There is big communication overhead between worker and main process.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy enough to demonstrate that using `setTimeout` (and by extension `setInterval`) you will never get millisecond accuracy.

The below demonstrates that even telling javascript to execute in 1 millisecond it can be anywhere from a few ms to tens of ms later the call is actually made.

```js
function recall(count){
  console.log(new Date())
  if(++count<10)
    setTimeout(recall,1,count);
}

recall(1)
```

You might have more luck with `requestAnimationFrame` but again you'll need to calculate how long has elapsed since last step and use that to "synchronise" whatever you want to do:

```js
let start;

function step(timestamp) {
  if (start === undefined)
    start = timestamp;
  const elapsed = timestamp - start;

  console.log(elapsed);
  
  if (elapsed < 500) { // Stop the animation after 0.5 seconds
    window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
  }
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
```

Comment: animation frame is not accurate enough, 30ms steps is way too high, but i guess i'll try to do some sort of "error mitigation" that removes discrepancy to the next timeout the error that the previous timeout had

Comment: @Specy yep, but (dont quote me on this) something in the back of my mind thinks animation frame is a bit more predictable than setTimeout

Comment: well, yes, but what if i have a a 40 ms timeout? it will run at every 2 frames, that's +-60 ms, +20 ms error.